# How to open function on Monday and close on Tuseday(next day)

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

There is a class with open and close functions. I use schedule library to open at 9:00 and close at 11:00. But how to do
 open--> on the first day at 19:00 and
 close--> next day at 11:00. ?

```
def workflow():
       schedule.every().day.at(9:00).do(open, smth)
       schedule.every().day.at(11:00).do(close, smth)
```

How to make it without splitting function workflow?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into `cron` if you are working on linux and `Task Scheduler` (I think) on Windows. For workflows that require a specific time triggers, I recommend using external tooling (such as the OS).

I recommend splitting the `open` and `close` into scripts that are triggered by the mentioned tools (or, any other automation tooling). It's easier to manage these configurations and doesn't require you to build software that's self aware of execution time frames.